# Why is the method to finding the order of a torsion subgroup different than finding the maximum order of a given element of a direct product?

Tags: abstract-algebra, torsion-groups

If we want to find the maximum order of a given element of say $\mathbb{Z}_3\times \mathbb{Z}_4$. We would have $lcm{(3,4)}=12$ is the maximum order. But if we take a look at finding the order of the torsion subgroup: $$\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_3$$ of $$\mathbb{Z}_{12} \times \mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}_{12}.$$ We would just take $4\times 3=12$ and $12\times 12=144$ for the orders, respectively. Why is it that the when finding the maximum order, you take the least common multiple but when finding the order of a torsion subgroup you just multiply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum order of an element in a finite group (also called the exponent of a group) is not the same as the order of the group.
The two are equal only if the group is cyclic.

In your example $\mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/4\mathbb Z$ the two are the same only because because the group is cyclic, isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/12\mathbb Z$.

However the Klein 4-group $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ has order 4 but exponent 2.

Comment: So the maximum order of a given element will be the least common multiple, while the order of the direct product itself is simply the product: $$|\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n| = (m)(n)$$ while $$\mbox{Max order of an element in} (\mathbb{Z}_m \times \mathbb{Z}_n) = lcm(m,n)$$The only time these two will equal is when we have relatively prime $m$ and $n$.

Comment: @Frumpy Yes, that is the gist of it. That is the reason why when decomposing finite abelian groups into sums of $\Bbb Z_n$'s, you can split any $n$ according to its maximal prime power divisors, but you cannot split the prime powers themselves, e.g. you can split $\Bbb Z_{36}$ into $\Bbb Z_4\times \Bbb Z_9$, but you cannot split the $4$ or $9$ any further (that would change the $\operatorname{lcm}$)

Comment: @Arthur So that is the reasoning behind why when you want to show isomorphism between two direct products of groups (finite integer groups), you can only change the group into a direct product of prime powers. For example: $$\mathbb{Z}_{24}=\mathbb{Z}_{2^3=8} \times \mathbb{Z}_3$$ and $$\mathbb{Z}_{24}\not=\mathbb{Z}_6 \times \mathbb{Z}_4$$